# Hawtio Compatibility with Camel 3.x

Tags: java, apache-camel, hawtio

We have recently upgraded Camel version in our application from `2.20.2` to `3.11.2`. Hawtio web console used to show some Camel related details with Camel 2.20.2 which are missing after the upgrade to 3.11.2. After doing some analysis, I found that Hawtio is trying to access some MBeans which Camel used to expose before, but not now after the upgrade.

[MBean not available](https://i.stack.imgur.com/68zyf.png)

I just want to check if Hawtio is compatible with Camel 3.x or not, or is there anything else that I'm missing.

Currently we are using:

- Camel 3.11.2 with Spring DSL
- Hawtio 2.13.0

Comment: Did you include the camel 3 `camel-management`dependency ? This lib is required for a complete integration with Hawtio. I've been using Camel3 with Hawtio2 for months without any problem

Comment: Yeah, have included camel-management in my Camel application. Even I can see most of the details in Hawtio web console but having troubles to access some of the information.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably missing one dependency.
Here is the full list of mines - ok probably too much as components are included in this list, but you will also find some basic one (like "camel-base-engine-3.9.0.jar").

```
camel-api-3.9.0.jar
camel-base-3.9.0.jar
camel-base-engine-3.9.0.jar
camel-bean-3.9.0.jar
camel-bindy-3.9.0.jar
camel-catalog-3.9.0.jar
camel-cdi-3.9.0.jar
camel-core-3.9.0.jar
camel-core-catalog-3.9.0.jar
camel-core-engine-3.9.0.jar
camel-core-languages-3.9.0.jar
camel-core-model-3.9.0.jar
camel-core-processor-3.9.0.jar
camel-core-reifier-3.9.0.jar
camel-core-xml-3.9.0.jar
camel-csv-3.9.0.jar
camel-direct-3.9.0.jar
camel-directvm-3.9.0.jar
camel-file-3.9.0.jar
camel-ftp-3.9.0.jar
camel-health-3.9.0.jar
camel-http-3.9.0.jar
camel-http-base-3.9.0.jar
camel-http-common-3.9.0.jar
camel-jackson-3.9.0.jar
camel-jaxb-3.9.0.jar
camel-json-validator-3.9.0.jar
camel-jsonpath-3.9.0.jar
camel-jta-3.9.0.jar
camel-log-3.9.0.jar
camel-main-3.9.0.jar
camel-management-3.9.0.jar
camel-management-api-3.9.0.jar
camel-microprofile-config-3.9.0.jar
camel-microprofile-health-3.9.0.jar
camel-microprofile-metrics-3.9.0.jar
camel-mock-3.9.0.jar
camel-seda-3.9.0.jar
camel-sjms-3.9.0.jar
camel-sjms2-3.9.0.jar
camel-support-3.9.0.jar
camel-timer-3.9.0.jar
camel-util-3.9.0.jar
camel-xml-jaxb-3.9.0.jar
camel-xml-jaxp-3.9.0.jar
camel-xpath-3.9.0.jar
```

Comment: Are you able to see component properties that I'm struggling with? (Please refer the image attached in the question.)